# Shorten the procedure

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to somehow shorten the procedure without using if, but use if in where?

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `getMailing`(in user_id int, by_no_activate boolean)
BEGIN
if by_no_activate then
select `name`, send_time, `type`, `active` from mailing where `userId` = user_id and `active` = False and send_type != 'now';
else
select `name`, send_time, `type`, `active` from mailing where `userId` = user_id;
end if; 
END
```

Comment: I would be more inclined to remove the parameter and make two procedures.

Comment: @user207421 there were originally two of them, but since they provide the same data, it was decided to combine them

Answer (score 3):

You can put an `IF()` condition in the `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT `name`, send_time, `type`, `active` 
from mailing 
where `userId` = user_id 
AND IF(by_no_activate, `active` = False and send_type != 'now', TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I already tried this option but without true at the end and got it wrong

Comment: @TopoR With this query usage (if none another actions in your SP is performed) you may remove BEGIN-END and omit DELIMITER.